# Calculating dates and adding them to a list using a starting date, number of days and a number of payment occurences

Tags: list, flutter, date, dart, flutter-layout

I have a starting date, a number of days before payment occurs and a number of payment occurrences.
I want to create a list that has all the dates on which the subsequent payments occur.
I know the way to go about is to add the number of days to the starting date. As i have done below:

```
 nextpaymentdate() {
    DateTime nextdate = startingDate!.add(Duration(days: 7));
    return nextdate;
  }
```

But how do i add the dates for all the payment occurences in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a for loop to create the list.

```dart
List paymentOccurences = [];
int numberOfPaymentOccurrences = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPaymentOccurrences; i++) {
    paymentOccurences.add(nextpaymentdate());
}
```

and then use something like ListView.builder to display it in flutter.
https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: paymentOccurences.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text(paymentOccurences[index]),
    );
  },
)
```